# How to localize Accessibility Label(Description) with Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

In order to add VoiceOver support for my app(using Interface Builder),I set a button's "Accessibility Identity -> Description" to "Mute" [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JORjq.png).This actually set accessibility label.
And now,I want to add localization for this button,including accessibility label of it.
How can I do that?

ps: I've tried the programmatically way(NSLocalizedString) and creating xib file for each language.But both of them are not good for maintenance.I want to know if I can localize it in ".strings" way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create extension like this and then set keys in UI Builder but handle localization in .strings file

```
@IBDesignable
public extension UIView {

    @IBInspectable
    var accessibilityLabelKey: String {
        get { return "" }
        set {
            self.accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString(newValue, comment:newValue)
        }
    }
}
```